# Sending and receiving data on the network using boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, marshalling

The project I am working on is in C++. In order to send and receive data on the network, I use boost library to serialize and deserialize and it works perfectly fine. The problem is that since I use serialization, it adds a huge amount of overhead on each message. For each field, it adds a field type. Since the message size is really critical and it should be as less as possible, I just want to send the real data. I use many arrays, which are created dynamically and as a result, I cannot easily send the pointers. For each and every pointers, I should go inside to sort of serialize it by myself.

Any idea how to make a use of boost serialization while keep the message size exactly to the real size.

Thanks

Comment: Compressing and decompresing could be considered as a good idea?

Comment: If boost serialization add too much overhead for you, you may want to switch to a library that adds nearly no size overhead, like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Comment: In http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html (reference), you can find Archive types.  Maybe the binary archive can be enough for you.

Comment: Use portable binary archive: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives